# Add animation to bootstrap 4 navbar in mobile without jquery

Tags: bootstrap-4

How to add animation to drop down bootstrap 4 in mobile layout created without jQuery?
I try using transition height 1s and 'all' without results.

Thanks for help.

```js
document.getElementById('navbar-toggler').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('navbarSupportedContent').classList.toggle('show')
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bootstrap library without jQuery, as the library has dependancy on jQuery (and popper too). [Introduction to Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/):

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
>   Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript
>   plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages,
>   right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come
>   first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.